# Transverse measures in pseudo-Anosov diffeomorphisms

Tags: foliations, surfaces, hyperbolic-dynamics, pullback, anosov-systems

I've recently begun doing research involving pseudo-Anosov diffeomorphisms, which are diffeomorphisms on surfaces $f : M \to M$ admitting two singular measured foliations $(\mathcal F^s, \nu^s)$ and $(\mathcal F^u, \nu^u)$. Frequently I've seen the following notation and I'm having trouble understanding it: 
$$
f(\mathcal F^s, \nu^s) = (\mathcal F^s, \nu^s/\lambda) \quad \textrm{and} \quad f(\mathcal F^u, \nu^u) = (\mathcal F^u, \lambda \nu^u)
$$
for some $\lambda > 1$. In this context, both $\mathcal F^s$ and $\mathcal F^u$ are foliations with the same (finite) set of singularities $S$, and $\nu^s$ and $\nu^u$ are transverse measures to the leaves of $\mathcal F^s$ and $\mathcal F^u$. In particular, if there's a coordinate chart $\phi : U \to \mathbb C$, with $U \subset M$ not containing any singularities, then the leaves of $\mathcal F^s$ and $\mathcal F^u$ are mapped to sets of the form $$\{z : \mathrm{Re}(z) = \mathrm{const}\} \cap \phi(U) \quad \textrm{and} \quad \{z : \mathrm{Im}(z) = \mathrm{const}\} \cap \phi(U)$$
respectively, and $\nu^s|_U$ and $\nu^u|_U$ are pullbacks of $|\mathrm{Re}(dz)|$ and $|\mathrm{Im}(dz)|$. A similar formula (with powers of complex variables) holds in coordinate neighborhoods with singularities.

**What I don't understand:** These pullback expressions imply if $\gamma$ is a plaque of $\mathcal F^s$, then since $\nu^s(\gamma) = 0$, we must have $\nu^u(\gamma) > 0$. Previously I had interpreted the notation $f(\mathcal F^u, \nu^u) = (\mathcal F^u, \lambda \nu^u)$ to mean that $\nu^u(f(\gamma)) = \lambda \nu^u(\gamma)$, for our $\lambda > 1$. However, in every paper on pseudo-Anosov maps I've read, it's clear that points in the same $\mathcal F^s$-leaf uniformly contract and points in the same $\mathcal F^u$-leaf uniformly expand, which is in direct contradiction to my interpretation. In particular, the exact *opposite* appears to be the case: $\nu^u(f(\gamma)) = \nu^u(\gamma)/\lambda$ for plaques of $\mathcal F^s$ and $\nu^s(f(\gamma)) = \lambda \nu^s(\gamma)$ for plaques of $\mathcal F^u$.

Can someone explain what the notation $f(\mathcal F^u, \nu^u) = (\mathcal F^u, \lambda \nu^u)$ and $f(\mathcal F^s, \nu^s) = (\mathcal F^s, \nu^s/\lambda)$ means? If points in the same stable leaf of $\mathcal F^s$ are uniformly contracting w.r.t. $\nu^u$ (which is obviously the case in regular Anosov systems) and in the unstable leaf are uniformly expanding w.r.t. $\nu^s$, why do we write $f(\mathcal F^s, \nu^s) = (\mathcal F^s, \nu^s/\lambda)$ and $f(\mathcal F^u, \nu^u) = (\mathcal F^u, \lambda \nu^u)$?

Comment: The transverse measures are the things that get scaled.  So the leaves of the stable foliation are expanding (it's the transverse curves that get contracted).

Comment: @Autumn Kent but if the leaves of the stable foliation are expanding, then does this mean the distance between points in the same stable leaf is growing by a factor of $\lambda$? Or do you mean something else? Because standard references on pseudo-Anosov systems (e.g. Fathi et al.'s "Thurston's Work on Surfaces") indicate that the distance between distinct points on stable leaves contracts.

Comment: Oh I see, I was getting confused by the notation and got things mixed up. See the discussion in FLP around Lemma 9.3.  For a transverse arc $\alpha$ the notation means that $\mu(f^{-1}(\alpha)) = \lambda \mu(\alpha)$.

Comment: Oh! I understand, so it's in reference to a pushforward measure, like the standard conventional definition of measure-invariance in ergodic theory. Thank you, that clears up everything!